# Remove similar data points from dataset

Tags: javascript, linear-regression

I am plotting a journey on google maps.  The amount of data is bringing the performance of the maps down so am looking for a way to reduce the amount of data.  Specifically I am looking to remove plot points that are very similar to each other.

I have an array of location data describing a persons journey.  Those data points are essentially a big list of lat/longs with some associated metadata, such as speed.

I remember that a linear regression model can be used to remove "similar" points that appear along a line based on location data only but can it be extended to also include another field, such as speed?

i.e. If I have the following points (I'll use X,Y rather than latlng for brevity).  Ill plot the points in a dia

- { Lat: 0, Lng: 0, Speed: 0 }
- { Lat: 1, Lng: 1, Speed: 0 } // could be removed
- { Lat: 2, Lng: 2, Speed: 1 } // could be removed
- { Lat: 3, Lng: 3, Speed: 30 } // big change, keep
- { Lat: 4, Lng: 4, Speed: 30 } // could be removed
- { Lat: 5, Lng: 5, Speed: 30 } // could be removed
- { Lat: 1, Lng: 5, Speed: 30 } // big change, keep

Can anyone give me some real code how do to this? I am using javascript but can convert from any language or pseudo code. If speed cannot be included could someone please help me with the linear regression algorithm just for similar plot points?

Apologies if my maths terminology isnt great, I'm a bit out of my depth maths wise!

Comment: Could you not just iterate through the array and compare each point to the previous point, throwing out those that aren't different enough?

Comment: How do you define different enough? What if there is a point between two points that is dissimilar in that it is completely inbetween the two, but when drawing a line between them it intersects perfectly so is redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using reduce to loop through all entries creating a new array , entries are ignored in case they're too similar with preceding entry ( `distance*speed > 5` );

```js
var data = [
  { Lat: 0, Lng: 0, Speed: 0 },
  { Lat: 1, Lng: 1, Speed: 0 }, // could be removed
  { Lat: 2, Lng: 2, Speed: 1 } ,// could be removed
  { Lat: 3, Lng: 3, Speed: 30 }, // big change, keep
  { Lat: 4, Lng: 4, Speed: 30 }, // could be removed
  { Lat: 5, Lng: 5, Speed: 30 }, // could be removed
  { Lat: 1, Lng: 5, Speed: 30 }
]

function distance(a,b){
    return Math.sqrt( Math.pow(a.Lat - b.Lat, 2) + Math.sqrt( Math.pow(a.Lng - b.Lng, 2) ))
}

function speedDif(a,b){
  return Math.abs(a.Speed - b.Speed)
}
var res = data.reduce((ac,x) =>{
  if(!ac.length)
    ac.push(x);
  else {
    const last = ac[ac.length -1 ];
    if(distance(last, x) * speedDif(last, x) > 5) //for ex.5
    ac.push(x)
  }
  return ac;
},[])

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for seems to be a simple distance calculator between points. So for each point, calculate distance to next point, and if it's greater than some predetermined distance you keep it, otherwise, remove it. The only problem with that is, say you go from (1,1) to (2,2) to (3,3) to (4,4) to... (1000,1000) and you keep on removing everything! My suggestion would be to compare each node to the previous one, calculate distance, and THEN if you're going to remove it, first compare it to the last node that you DID NOT remove. This way, even if you keep removing  multiple nodes that are close to each other, you'll still know when you've gotten far enough from the last node you included. This is just an approach to do it without all the nasty linear regression stuff...